# Counting the number of "selected" table cells in a column with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

I have a table with 5 columns where I need the user to "select" and "unselect" cells. Then, I need to have a running total kept of how many cells in each COLUMN as "selected".

I am selecting the cells with a simple toggle function, changing the class of the cell

```
$('td').toggle(function() {
 $(this).addClass("selectedCell");
 }, function() {
 $(this).removeClass("selectedCell");
});
```

So I suppose what I need to do is get all the cells in each column whose current class is "selectedCell" and assign it to a 5 variables so I can display "you selected 3 items from column 4" (for example).

How would I best accomplish this?

Comment: "...and assign it to a 5 variables so I can display..." - I'm sorry, but what do you mean by 'assign it to a 5 variables'?

Comment: My bad, I did not realize.  I will remedy this right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how your table is setup to handle 'columns' but to get a total of selected cells in the table, use this:

```
$('table').find('td.selectedCell').length
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/tYT2E/

If you changed your table setup to a div structure, it would be much easier to calculate what you need:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="selectedCell">1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div class="selectedCell">3</div>
        <div class="selectedCell">4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div class="selectedCell">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="selectedCell">8</div>
        <div class="selectedCell">9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        ..........
    </div>
</div>
<div id="status"></div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function update_counts(){
    $('#status').html('');
    $('.column').each(function(index){
       $('#status').append($(this).find('.selectedCell').length + ' selected cells in column ' + (index + 1) + '<br />');
    }); 
}

$('.column div').click(function(){

    // Add or remove class
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedCell');

    // Update the class counts
    update_counts();

});

// Run the function on domready
$(function(){
    update_counts();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/tYT2E/4/

Comment: Further question @AlienWebguy:  How would i best store the selected count in variables?  For my project there are 3 tables, and I need to add the column counts of each together (all the col 1s, all the col 2s, etc.)

Comment: For example, adding a second table http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/MhwNR/1/ essentially just makes the first table larger.  Should I just create a new column class for each table?

Comment: No, it's cuz you gave the 2nd wrapper the same id. It's easy to add these variables. I made a new example for you where we assign the selected_count to the `data()` object like such: `$('#table1').data('col4',5) // 5 selected in table 1, column 4` -- this is all dynamic on the click event. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/MhwNR/2/ It will alert the selected_count for table 1, column 4, so click a few of those to see it update.

Comment: So, I assume if I want to have a column runninng total, I would  do `column4 = $('#table1').data('col4') + $('#table2').data('col4');` and to diplay it `$('#status').append('total 4s = '+column4);`

Comment: @AlienWebguy OK, one last question.  I got it working basically the way I need to, see: http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/8zY8C/ However, technically users should only be able to select one item per row.  How could I check on click that a selection exists for that row, and pop an alert telling the user "one item per row please"?